# Find Smallest Value in DataFrame by using GroupBy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data like this:

```
Index SourceID  ComparedID  Distance
571   106       8           0.004846
572   106       11          0.000000
573   106       23          0.012712
574   107       84          0.002800
575   107       70          0.007555
```

It is in a `pandas` dataframe. I am trying to figure out how to do this:

I want to create a result from the dataframe that find the smallest distance and returns the `ComparedID`.

So the output would look like:

```
SourceID ComparedID Distance
106      11         0.000000
107      84         0.002800
```

How can I do this?

Comment: did one of the below answers help? if so, feel free to accept (tick on left) or ask more questions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you require so I have included 2 options below.

**1. No Grouping by SourceID**

This is one way to get the 2 smallest Distances:

```
df.nsmallest(2, columns=['Distance'])

#    Index  SourceID  ComparedID  Distance
# 1    572       106          11    0.0000
# 3    574       107          84    0.0028
```

To return just a list of ComparedIDs:

```
df.nsmallest(2, columns=['Distance'])['ComparedID'].tolist()

# [11, 84]
```

**2. Grouping by SourceID**

The idea here is to sort by Distance, then drop duplicates by SourceID:

```
df.sort_values('Distance').drop_duplicates('SourceID')
```

Result:

```
   Index  SourceID  ComparedID  Distance
1    572       106          11    0.0000
3    574       107          84    0.0028
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use idxmin()

```
df.iloc[df.groupby('SourceID')['Distance'].idxmin(), :]

    Index   SourceID    ComparedID  Distance
1   572     106         11          0.0000
3   574     107         84          0.0028
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.sort_values(by='Distance').groupby('SourceID').agg('first')
```

you want to sort the data frame by distance, and for each `'SourceID'` get the row with the smallest distance, i.e. the first row for each group.

The above produces the following output:

```
        Index   ComparedID  Distance
SourceID            
106     572     11          0.0000
107     574     84          0.0028
```

When you use the group by, the grouped columns end up being indexed, you can *flatten* the data frame by subsequently resetting the index as well to get the output that you want

```
df.sort_values(by='Distance').groupby('SourceID').agg('first').reset_index()
```

outputs:

```
    SourceID    Index   ComparedID  Distance
0   106         572     11          0.0000
1   107         574     84          0.0028
```